# How can I cd from parent1/suba/subb to parent2/suba/subb without listing subdirectories?

Tags: bash, cd-command

I have multiple parent directories with the same file structure beneath them.

**Example:**

```
parent1/suba/subb/
parent2/suba/subb/
```

When I am in `parent1/suba/subb`, I would like to change to `parent2/suba/subb` without doing something like `cd ../../../parent2/suba/subb`. How can I do this without listing all the subdirectories and `../`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`PWD` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PWD) and [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) constructs to quickly apply a text transformation to the current directory.

```
cd ${PWD/parent1/parent2}
```

This doesn't have to be exactly a path component, it can be any substring. For example, if the paths are literally `parent1` and `parent2`, and there is no character `1` further left in the path, you can use `cd ${PWD/1/2}`. The search string can contain several path components, but then you need to escape the slash. For example, to go from `~/checkout/trunk/doc/frobnicator/widget` to `~/checkout/bugfix/src/frobnicator/widget`, you can use `cd ${PWD/trunk\/doc/bugfix/src}`. More precisely, the `parent1` part is a shell wildcard pattern, so you can write something like `cd ${PWD/tr*c/bugfix/src}`.

In [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-cd), you can use the shorter syntax `cd parent1 parent2`. Again, you can replace any substring in the path (here, this is exactly a substring, not a wildcard pattern).

You can implement a similar function in bash.

```
cd () {
  local options
  options=()
  while [[ $1 = -[!-]* ]]; do options+=("$1"); shift; done
  if (($# == 2)); then
    builtin cd "${options[@]}" "${PWD/$1/$2}"
  else
    builtin cd "${options[@]}" "$@"
  fi
}
```

Zsh provides completion for the second argument. Implementing this in bash is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great answer! It's also possible to only replace the differing sections in the path without specifying the entire directory name. So assuming that `1` does not appear elsewhere the path for the example, you can do `cd ${PWD/1/2}`.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 Indeed, I've added a paragraph to expand on this. I've also added a bash function to get zsh-like behavior, which avoids having to type that `${PWD//}` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

first time

if parent1 ou parent 2 are elsewhere in directory path.

```
cd $(pwd | sed -e s:/parent1/:/parent2/: )
```

then if you switch *only* from those two directory

```
cd -
```

- will bring you back to the dir you jump from.

Answer (score 1):

You can `set` the target directories to the positional array. For example:

```
cd ~
mkdir dirtest
cd dirtest
i=0
until [ "$((i=$i+1))" -gt 9 ] 
do mkdir -p parent"$i"/suba/subb
done
```

That creates a tree modeled after the example in the question, with parents 1-9. I can now:

```
set -- "$PWD/parent"[0-9]"/suba/subb"
cd "$1"; pwd
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/home/mikeserv/dirtest/parent1/suba/subb
```

...and because the `[0-9]` glob expansion is sorted according to locale...

```
cd "$5"; pwd

/home/mikeserv/dirtest/parent5/suba/subb

cd "$9"; pwd

/home/mikeserv/dirtest/parent9/suba/subb
```

...works for 0-9. But the shell will likely not sort *parent10* after *parent9*, and will instead sort it after *parent1*. It will, however, likely sort *parent10* after *parent09*, though. Once you get into double-digits you should use the `${parameter expansion}` braces around the number to explicitly reference `"${10}"` rather than `"$1"` then `0`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `pwd` and `sed`  to replace the differences in the path like this:

```
cd `pwd | sed 's/parent1/parent2/'`
```

or like this:

```
cd $( pwd | sed 's/parent1/parent2/' )
```

In some cases (like the example) you do not need to specify the entire directory, and you can just replace the differing parts:

```
cd `pwd | sed 's/1/2/'`
```

Answer (score 0):

My `.bahsrc` has a function named `cd-e` (cd-edit).

```
cd-e (){  PWD=`echo "$PWD" | vipe +'normal $'`;  cd "$PWD"; }
```

It opens the current directory in `vim`, with the cursor positioned at the end (because I tend to edit closer to the end).

(
Vipe is part of `moreutils`, or something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"' exit
tmp=`mktemp`
cat > "$tmp"
</dev/tty vi "$@" "$tmp" >/dev/tty
cat "$tmp"
```

)

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most common way to do such stuff is to use an alias:

```
alias dir1='cd parent1/suba/subb/'
```